# Does the decay energy of a beta decaying isotope become lower as the half life becomes greater (or vice versa)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

In other words, does half life have a correlation with decay energy of a beta particle?

Comment: Do you mean the energy of the beta particles?!?

Comment: Yes, I mean the energy of the beta particles

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis yes, I mean the energy of the beta particles

Comment: Then no. The decays of past nuclei do not influence the decay of a nucleus in any way: they are all independent from each others.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Please answer in an answer instead of in a comment.

Comment: Feel free to write a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this question is ***yes***.

The reason is wrapped up in "[weak universality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11664/520)": the idea that all weak interaction at low energy share a common underlying process that controls the one of the two factors that go into determining rates for spontaneous processes. That leaves the phase space available to the products as the thing that almost solely determined the lifetime.

In short the phase space available to the interaction depends to a large degree on the total energy and to a much smaller degree on the mass of the recoiling remnant nucleus.

I gave a rather more complete treatment in [another answer about the free neutron lifetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/31517/520).